# Choosing between a Canon 600D(Rebel T3i) and a Nikon D90

Tags: canon, nikon, nikon-d90, camera-recommendation, canon-600d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Canon t2i or new Nikon d90?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4937/canon-t2i-or-new-nikon-d90)

I am planning to buy my first DSLR camera. I am however not sure which one to choose from Nikon 90 or Canon 600D(Rebel T3i ). I particularly like to  low light, outdoors and macro photography. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Really, check the T2i vs D90 question, everything applies to this case too.

Answer (score 0):

When choosing between brands of camera, I feel that it is more important to examine other factors beyond the features within one particular model.

Canon and Nikon have different ranges of lenses, accessories, and 3rd party add-ons. They also take slightly different approaches to their ranges of cameras. Canon, for example, has a much broader selection of lenses, with inexpensive lenses up to top of the line pro lenses, and everything in between. Nikon does not have as broad a range, and there is less distinction between its high end and top of the line lenses. Both have good 3rd party support.

As for camera bodies, these seem to mirror one another, though Canon seems to be the more prolific of the two, and appears to be focusing on frequent updates to the lower end of cameras. The benefit is that Canon's lower end models tend to get dramatically better over time.  I would rate both Canon and Nikon equivalent here.

Both have good selections in flashes and other bits, but all Nikon cameras support off-camera remote flash, whereas with Canon, only the 7D at the moment supports this feature. Canon has more models with video support as well.

Both Nikon and Canon have a very broad range of 3rd party support, with essentially any kind of accessory being available. This is usually not the case with other brands of camera, such as Olympus and Pentax, where 3rd party selection can be extremely rare.

Comment: I don't think the third-party situation for non-Canon/Nikon is as dire as you paint it. There's no question that the big two get more support, being a bigger market, but "extremely rare" is frankly ridiculous. Most types of accessories work regardless of camera brand, and the ones that are system specific actually usually _are_ offered for Pentax, Sony, Olympus/Panasonic. There are exceptions, but _that's_ the rare case.

Comment: Third-party support depends on what. For lenses, 3rd-parties offer roughly 50% more lenses for the major two but for specialized accessories (UW housings, camera protection, custom plates, etc) it is sadly true that  support is much more limited. Note that some brands have it worst than others. Sony gets the least third-party flashes because they use a different connector and Pentax gets the least third-party lenses because of the non-compete agreement with Tokina due to shared designs.