# Selling and buying a DSLR

Tags: equipment-recommendation

Hi all need some advice, thinking of selling my Olympus E420 and buying a full frame DSLR. I bought the Olympus thinking that a smaller camera would mean I take it to more places but when combined with the lenses the body really makes no difference.

So selling.. any recommendations on where best to sell? Thinking e-Bay and Gumtree at the moment. I have a 14-42 and 70-300 lens, should I sell these separately or with the camera

Should I buy new or buy second hand? Which lens? I hate swapping lenses so maybe a 25-150?

Bit of background which may help, I am amateur that wants to get into photography. I mainly photograph when on holiday at the moment and am planning to take couple of short courses one studio and one wildlife photography. I enjoy landscapes, wildlife and architecture. Do enjoy night photography also. http://flikr.com/rakkhi

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This sounds like it might be better split into several questions.

Comment: The brand-vs-brand debate should be removed entirely. That's never going to be productive — or in the Stack Exchange lingo, it ends up being _subjective and argumentative_. Instead, take a look at http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/175/what-are-considerations-when-choosing-a-dslr-brand

Comment: I don't think you know what full-frame means. The 550D is not a full-frame camera.

Comment: anything is "full frame" for a given definition of "full frame"...

Comment: @Om - Full-frame normally means the imaging sensor is the same size as 35mm film. This makes your camera bigger, means it needs bigger lenses and a bigger budget ;) It has an advantage when it comes to image noise.

Comment: See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/used-equipment for some questions which cover concerns about buying used.

Comment: Shooting landscape, wildlife, architecture, night photography, and studio shots - means you'll have to own pretty much every lens lol.  Plan on a large pack ;)

Comment: I'll start small and build up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selling equipment on eBay is OK but you should also try Craigslist and Kikiji. The time-limit for eBay auctions make it harder to get a good value. Also locals can see and handle the gear which gives it higher perceived value. That being said, I've sold through all 3.

Canon vs Nikon is an eternal theme which only has subjective answers. Handle at least one full-frame camera of each brand. You may prefer the control placement and logic of one or the other. The second important thing to consider are lenses since the vendor controls which lens you have access to. Both Canon and Nikon have a wide-range of lenses but you may find some lenses that suit your needs better with one brand.

For low-light photography, [Nikon's D3S](http://www.neocamera.com/camera.php?id=10) is extremely interesting due to its larger pixels, at the expense of higher resolution. This is a niche Nikon has for itself now.

If you want a single lens, you have to make compromises depending on the range you want. For something not too dim and starts ultra-wide, the [Nikkor 24-120mm F/4](http://www.neocamera.com/lens.php?id=43) or [Canon 24-105mm F/4](http://www.neocamera.com/lens.php?id=174) are quite good. Both Nikon and Canon have an ultra-zoom 28-300mm F/3.5-5.6 which is rather dim at the long end.

Answer (score 1):

Canon vs. Nikon:  You can't go wrong with either, highly suggest you visit a camera store and hold the cameras, as they vary in size, weight and the feel in your hand.

Personally, I buy most lenses 2nd hand.  I wouldn't buy a body 2nd hand unless it was from someone I knew and trusted - there is a lot more to go wrong with a camera body than a lens.

It might pay to do your photography courses and put off buying more gear until you have learned more?

Comment: Thanks yes will go to a camera store and try out the body. Leaning towards the Canon 6D at the moment. Need to think about the 2nd hand lens, maybe a good idea. Good advice on doing the courses first I will do that

Answer (score 0):

Regarding selling, here is my experience:

I prefer to sell where the photographers go, which includes some of the popular boards, like Digitalgrin.com (Smugmug), FredMiranda.com, and Photography-on-the.net. On these boards, you will likely find that most buyers are looking for a specific camera body or lens, so they sell better separately.  However, selling as a bundle is great for a beginner, so I recommend pricing as a bundle, and then offer separate pricing where you should consider a discounted price for the bundle over separate pricing per piece.

The alternative is to sell your gear to reputable photo gear vendors, where you can also get a good indication of the bottom price you should consider for your gear. So, visit KEH.com, Adorama.com and BHphoto.com and get quotes on selling them your gear. Then you have both a base price and a fall back should you not find a buyer on the boards.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not i n a rush so I will get a price from the camera stores as you suggest and then try the auction boards

Answer (score 0):

From your questions you are at a place where all of us have been and now you are looking for guidance as you move forward. That is an entirely reasonable thing to do.

But the problem is that you are asking us to recommend a path that you take. We cannot do that because we cannot ever know enough about your circumstances, goals and needs.

What we can do is give you information that will help you to make your own decision.

So please ask yourself what specific information you need in  order to make your decisions. We will try and provide that information. But do not ask us to recommend the decision itself. That is something you must do.

Note also that we strive to be vendor neutral. We do not take sides when it comes to make of camera, lens or buying/selling sites. Once again, that kind of decision is only one you can make for yourself.

Comment: Actually the information provided so far has been very usefull. I will ask more specific questions based on this though. Thanks for empathising!

Comment: @Rakkhi, I am glad you have found it helpful. There has been an ongoing debate about the nature of this site and you have fallen into the crosshairs of that debate!! Have you tried posting your questions in one or more of the forums at DPReview.com? It has a large, active (and partisan) membership that will give you a good range of views.

Comment: I have not tried dpreview forums but I got some really good advice just creating a facebook group of friends that are into photography. Some really do hardcore research. Thanks again for your help