# Canon or nikon?

Tags: canon, nikon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any significant difference between Nikon and Canon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-nikon-and-canon)

I am a starter in photography. I want buy my first DSLR (Nikon D5100 or canon 600D) and I am in a big confusion to which brand to choose. Which brand's lenses are cheaper and good. Which brand's has a better service center.

Comment: You should check this existing question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-nikon-and-canon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both make great cameras, great lenses and are both supported by all 3rd party accessories.

I don't know about service centers but I guess it depends on the specific service center, maybe even the specific technician that services your camera.

Unless you have very special needs, both options are wonderful; choose the camera that fits in your hands better (or, if you can't try it out the one that is cheaper — or the one that looks better — it doesn't really matter).