# What are the striking differences between Canon and Nikon?

Tags: canon, nikon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any significant difference between Nikon and Canon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-nikon-and-canon)

I have recently bought a Nikon D5100 and a Nikon 18-135mm lens. This is my first DSLR and am very happy with it.

I wanted to know what are the striking differences between Nikon and Canon on a broader perspective. For example, something which is only possible with a Canon DSLR or a Nikon DSLR (considering that both have a similar range of lenses). If any such difference exists, why is the other brand not providing it? Also, what are the features that make them unique among various other brands?