# Nikon D810 vs Canon 5D Mark 4 for portraits

Tags: canon, nikon, nikon-d810

Which is a better camera for portraits, the Nikon D810 or Canon 5D Mark 4?

Comment: This is a subjective question and has no right or wrong answer. Either camera, used by a skilled photographer, is capable of professional quality results.

Comment: Which lenses one selects with either camera will make a far larger difference than the differences between these two cameras.

Comment: Lighting also has a huge impact.  I notice from a previous question you have a Nikon D750.  It's a very capable DSLR and changing camera is unlikely to get you anything useful for portraits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any significant difference between Nikon and Canon?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-nikon-and-canon)

Comment: No. Definitely not :-). 
Neither is the better camera for portraits.

Comment: Define 'better'.

Answer (score 3):

The camera is not what makes a portrait, but rather the photographer. Neither camera is necessarily better for portraits; both models (and indeed many others) have all the features one needs.

Comment: "Both have all the features one needs" is pretty subjective. I, for example, need an AF array that covers the whole frame, neither of the cameras offers it.

Comment: @KamenMinkov Portraits with very shallow field are small subset of portraits.