# Canon 1300D vs Nikon D3300

Tags: canon, nikon, equipment-recommendation

I am confused between the [Canon EOS Rebel T6 1300D](https://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/slrs/canon_eos1300d) and the [Nikon D3300](https://www.dpreview.com/reviews/nikon-d3300).  While the Canon has an in-built wireless it seems to be an inferior camera to the Nikon but they cost about the same.

Are these two cameras really as equivalent as the price suggests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any significant difference between Nikon and Canon?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-nikon-and-canon)

Comment: Welcome to Photo.StackExchange Abdel.  I fear this question will drive opinion-based answers and not really be answerable.  Worse, it looks like you are asking a rhetorical question as you state your not interested in comparisons.  Perhaps you could edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: sorry for that because i am new in this forum , what can i do to answer this question please ? i just want to know what adventage the canon 1300d has in front of nikon  d3300 
i just feel like i am missing some features

Comment: Abdel, perhaps you should take a look here [How do I ask a good question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and then review the question that @mattdm linked to in his comment above.

Comment: See also [this earlier discussion on a different X vs Y question](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/why-are-you-voting-down-my-xs-vs-xsi-question/1084#1084) for why we generally avoid this sort of thing. In this particular case, I think you're getting downvotes because the title sounds confrontational, and regardless of any agreement or disagreement, we _really_ want to avoid the partisan my-brand-is-better squabbling common to many online camera forums.

Comment: To take pictures?

Answer (score 2):

The Canon EOS Rebel T6 1300D has a smaller sensor (18 mega-pixels) than the Nikon D3300 (24 mega-pixels).

That is not the whole story.  The Canon is a newer camera design with newer hardware.  Canon designed it specifically for the entry level dSLR photographer.  The Nikon D3300 is a three year old design and while still valuable (I use one) it does not have all of the newest features.

Its like trying to compare this year's Honda Accord with a four year old Jeep Compass because the dealer wants the same for both cars.

Answer (score 1):

With DSLRs you are buying into a system You are comparing one element of each of the systems, however when adding lenses/flashes etc into the mix the result could be closer/swing the other way.

A reason someone could choose the on paper inferior camera is that they have friends/family with Canon gear that they would be able to share.