# Comparing lenses

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I already have a Nikon camera SLR and I am planning on buying a backup camera also. My question is are the lenses for Nikon more expensive then for Canon. I am trying to keep expenses down for the lenses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any significant difference between Nikon and Canon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-nikon-and-canon)

Comment: Why would you buy a separate set of lenses for a "backup" camera? To me, "backup camera" sounds like a spare body that you'd keep in your bag in case something goes wrong with your primary body, and if that's the case you don't need any additional lenses -- just use the ones you have for your existing camera.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much do lens lineups vary across DSLR platforms?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9355/how-much-do-lens-lineups-vary-across-dslr-platforms)

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you would get a backup camera of the same brand so that they can share lenses.

Although you may find the average price of lenses for one brand to be lower than the other, there are a lot of lenses offered at different price-points by both brands. You will even find third-party brands to get the same lens for different mounts at exactly the same price.

Answer (score 2):

Both Nikon and Canon have lenses that are expensive, lenses that are more consumer oriented, and a little bit of everything in between. Other camera makers do as well, although their lens lineups aren't as broad in range as those offered by Canon or Nikon. There are third party lens makers that also make lenses for a variety of mounts, including Nikon and Canon, that range from very cheap to very expensive.

**In the case of a person who already has a camera for one system or the other, though, it usually makes a lot more sense for any additional cameras to also be in that same system so that lenses in that mount can be used on either camera as the need might arise.** It might even make sense to select one system over another if one has several friends who already have a collection of lenses in one particular mount or the other so that they can be loaned or traded.

There are a few cases of unique lenses offered by one or the other that might lead a shooter to by a camera in a system other than the one in which most of their gear is made, but those lenses aren't usually budget lenses. They tend to be on the other end of the price spectrum.

Rather than ask about "lenses" in general, it would probably be more beneficial to consider a specific photographic task one has in mind and search both systems to see which has the lens which best meets your criteria both photographically as well as in terms of cost.