# What does a beginner need to shoot sky or nature on budget?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I am 16 years old and want to begin with photography. I have budget of around 200 euros, with a maximum of 250 euros. I want to make some shots of the sky or of nature, so a good optical zoom would be helpful. I don't really know what to buy.

Comment: You want to shoot a day sky or a night sky? And by nature you mean animals or landscapes?

Comment: This may go along the same lines as this closed question - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12639/what-is-a-good-starter-camera-considering-price-and-value

Comment: well i offen go to the wood next where i live and there i take pictures of animals and the flowers but whit my parents i go on vacation to mountains offen so making a great pic of the whole landscape should be incredible ans day and night skys could be there to.

Comment: ok a bridge camera looks fine but could someone just suggest some to me into my budget pleas couze i didnt realy find one

Comment: oh and before i forgett: is it possible to change the lens on a bridge camera?

Comment: @théo: no, generally a "bridge" camera is an attached-lens affair. Smaller, non-SLR cameras with interchangeable lenses are generally called "system cameras", or "mirrorless interchangeable lens compacts" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how "far" you want to go on photography, for now. If you want just to start and get to know what photography is, I recommend you a Bridge. It gives you plenty of things to learn. If you just want to take snapshots on trips, go for a Compact.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to get heavily involved in photography, and spend more money later, then for that price range, I would probably recommend buying a used DSLR with a kit zoom lens.

This will be enough to begin learning, and find where you feel limited.  When you feel limited, that is the time to upgrade.  I would suggest your next upgrade would be a new lens or two... and then eventually you can upgrade your camera body, and continue using your new lenses.

Comment: and what kind of lenses should there be on te buyed DSLR like a 18-55 or something ?

Comment: 18-55 or any other wide angle is great for (wide) landscapes

Comment: @théo: Most canon DSLRs (except the higher-end ones) tend to sell with an 18-55 lens. It's not a luxury lens by any means, but will be a good start if you're just learning. And as DiAlex says, will be good for landscapes.