# Is there any bridge camera with an interchangeable lens?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, body, bridge-camera

In another question, I read that to begin with a budget of 250 Euro max, I could get a bridge camera. But are there any with the possibly to change the lens?

Comment: That's an oxymoron. The bridge is precisely the fixed-lens camera that has full manual controls.

Answer (score 6):

Having a non-interchangeable lens in an SLResque body with a compact-camera image sensor is pretty much the definition of a bridge camera, so I think you are out of luck :)

You might want to look into the four-thirds system instead or one of the other mirrorless jobs, but 250 Euro isn't enough to get into it I think.

Comment: SQLesque? Is that a typo for SLResque or is it a camera term I don't know?

Comment: Sorry, brainfart. You are quite correct of course.

Comment: I figure you're probably work with databases in your day job, eh? :)

Comment: How'd you ever guess? Yes, I do :)

Comment: I want an SQLesque camera; it will make photo cataloging easier.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you define the term. Generally, no.

"Bridge cameras" are a category that "bridges the gap" between point and shoot cameras and something better — where "something better" is usually understood to be a DSLR, and the idea that it's a "bridge" *usually* implies that it has advanced features and manual control — but it also might mean that it's a relatively bulky superzoom, which might not really offer a lot of control or even high image quality but *kinda looks like an SLR*, and so "bridges" the difference only in appearance.

Some might even argue that this size/weight similarity is the most important part of the definition, and that relatively advanced compact cameras like the Fujifilm X10 or Canon G12 don't count, because even though they have high image quality and advanced manual control, *they're not the right size and shape*. Or, someone might put the line somewhere *between* those two models, arguing that the X10 is too compact to count.

To add to the confusion, in the time since the term was invented there's a new category of cameras: compact *mirrorless interchangeable-lens system cameras*. The lower end models of these are designed to compete with P&S cameras, and the higher end models to compete with digital SLRs, so in that sense these are *very much* "bridge" cameras — but since "bridge camera" had a meaning long before this category existed, they typically don't count.

From the point of view of your particular question, the starting price for these interchangeable cameras is generally much above your maximum of €250 — so from that practical standpoint, you are probably out of luck. You may be able to find an older-model or used Olympus Pen or Sony Nex for not too much more — but you should be able find similar-vintage DSLR in the same price range, so if the reason you're looking at this type of camera is simply cost, that doesn't simply the decision.

Comment: otherwise look at the question what camera does a novice need for making^pictures of sky and nature on budget in a answer someone says that i need a bridge camera

Comment: This question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17501/what-does-a-beginner-need-to-shoot-sky-or-nature-on-budget. Yeah. It might be the right answer, but it really depends on the person and how much they plan to do, how much they plan to grow their photography, and how much flexibility they have to stretch their budget above initial plans.

Comment: well i realy need to learn the basics i dont know a sh** about photography and a friend of me sais that with a good camera everything is possible but i dont know im not sure. and by searching info i saw that optical zoom is much better than digital zoom does there existe some cameras with much optical zoom for my budget ?

Comment: It's true that optical zoom is better than digital zoom. But, it's not necessarily the case that zoom is important at all for learning the basics. See for example the answers to [this question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8939/). I think at this stage the most important thing is to get _any camera at all_ and start taking pictures. When you run into problems, experiment and ask questions. Soon, you'll better learn where your equipment isn't up to what you want it for — and where you have more to learn with what you have. Then you can make a good decision about where to go next.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "bridge" is in the old sense (and @mattdm gives a nice explanation here for why it may not), then you still have the option of getting a "bridge" that can accommodate a lens add-on. For example, the Canon S5IS (old, but this is the one I have for reference) has compatible wide angle and tele converters that can be attached to its lens to effectively widen the zoom range of the camera. Surely more modern compacts have similar options.